# Symfony2.7 でテーブルからエンティティを作りたい

Tags: symfony2

初めて質問致します。
kaz_dev と申します。

Symfony2を使ってWebアプリケーションを作りたいと思っています。

デーベースを作成したあと、エンティティのクラスファイルを生成したいです。
試したところ、手順「3.」でエラーが表示されます。

1.MySQLにテーブルを作成する

```
mysql> show tables;
Tables_in_sf2rentacar
car_class
location
reservation
user
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

2.テーブルからXML形式のマッピングファイルを作成する

```
$php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/RentacarBundle/Resource/config/doctrine --from-database --force
$ls ./src/Acme/RentacarBundle/Resource/config/doctrine/
./  ../  CarClass.orm.xml  Location.orm.xml  Reservation.orm.xml  User.orm.xml
```

3.エンティティファイルを作成する

```
$php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeRentacarBundle annotaion

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Bundle "AcmeRentacarBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBun
  dles() method of your AppKernel.php file?

doctrine:mapping:import [--em [EM]] [--filter FILTER] [--force] [--] <bundle> [<mapping-type>]
```

AcmeRentacarBundle が存在しない・・・ということですが、
何か手順が違っていたり、設定が必要でしょうか。

Symfony2.0.11 と Symfony2.7でのconsoleコマンドの違いについても
わかっていない状況です。

開発環境 (OS Linux)

```
$php -v
PHP 5.6.16 (cli) (built: Dec  9 2015 11:59:40)
$php app/console --version
Symfony version 2.7.13 - app/dev/debug

$mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.11, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

よろしくお願い致します。

[参考書籍]
効率的なWebアプリケーションの作り方
著者：小川雄大
技術評論社
書籍の内容の動作環境
OS Mac OS X 10.7
PHP 5.4.0
MySQL 5.5
Symfony 2.0.11

Answer (score 1):

> Bundle "AcmeRentacarBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file?

ということなので、AppKernel.php に AcmeRentacarBundle を記述していないのではないでしょうか。
`$bundles = array()`の要素に AcmeRentacarBundle を追加します。